# AlertDialog Closing Automatically

Tags: java, android, filter, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` for showing a small form to the user.

On the ALertDialog are 2 buttons; namely "Submit" & "Cancel".

Now the fields (EditTexts) have setKeyListeners attached to them individually.

The problem which I face is suppose the user doesn't fills in any field and directly clicks on `Submit` button then the dialog box closes automatically.

Here's my Method which is called for creating/showing the Dialog Box:

```
Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
LinearLayout layoutCreateMerch = new LinearLayout(ctx);
layoutCreateMerch.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layoutCreateMerch.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Store.this);
alert.setTitle("New Store");
final EditText stoName = new EditText(Store.this);
final EditText stoDesc = new EditText(Store.this);


InputFilter[] FilterMaxLen = new InputFilter[1];
FilterMaxLen[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(25);

stoName.setFilters(FilterMaxLen);
stoName.setHint("Store's Name");
stoName.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,&apos;1234567890 ")); 
stoName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
layoutCreateMerch.addView(stoName);

stoDesc.setFilters(FilterMaxLen);
stoDesc.setHint("Store's Description");
stoDesc.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,&apos;1234567890 ")); 
stoDesc.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
layoutCreateMerch.addView(stoDesc);

ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(ctx);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroll.addView(layoutCreateMerch);

alert.setView(scroll);

alert.setNeutralButton("Submit",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                if (Name.getText().toString().equals("") 
                        || Desc.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {

                    if(stoName.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        stoName.setHint("fill Store's Name");
                        stoName.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    else{}
                    if( stoDesc.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        stoDesc.setHint("fill Store's Description");
                        stoDesc.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    else{}
                    if..
                    ..
                    ..

                } 

                else {

                    System.out.println("should not exit :| ");
                }

            }
        });

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int whichButton) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
alert.show();
```

Any advice is appreciated..
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `addTextChangedListener` for your `EditText` and then always check user have entered any text or not as if not `disable` the submit button else `enable` the submit button dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But this is about filtering text.. :|

Comment: what exactly you are looking for ?? as if you click on alert dialog buttons, dialogs will be dismissed its a default behavior. Thats why i suggest you to disable the button if user have not entered anything. And by the way its not at all bout filtering text.

Comment: even if I set it as `.setNeutralButton` ? I think it should honor the `dialog.dismiss()` and not close automatically :|

Comment: who said i mean where you found as neutral will not dismiss the dialog, you can set setCancelable flag as false to alert dialog if you really don't want to dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Setting the Dialog box's `setCancelable` flag to `false` din't helped either :( Thanks for reminding me about the default behaviour of dialog boxes :D